# clojure conch's shell api doesn't show result for external commands like java

Tags: shell, clojure

I want to use clojure script for development tasks on my project, like running project using clojure script etc.

I used [lein-off lein plugin](https://github.com/mtyaka/lein-oneoff) and clojure conch library for shell api, script is as below (`dubofsky.clj`)

```
(defdeps                                                                                                                                                                         
    [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]                                                                                                                       
     [me.raynes/conch "0.8.0"]])                                                                    

(ns deploy                                                                                          
    (use [clojure.java.shell :only  [sh]])                                                          
    (:require [me.raynes.conch.low-level :as shell]))

  (sh "sh" "-c" "echo hello > /dev/null")
  (print (shell/stream-to-string (shell/proc "echo" "....................................") :out))
  (print (shell/stream-to-string (shell/proc "echo" "Project starting...") :out))
  (print (shell/stream-to-string (shell/proc "grails" "run-app") :out))
  (print (shell/stream-to-string (shell/proc "bash" "--version") :out))
```

However on `lein oneoff dubofsky.clj`, it doesn't seem to print output of external commands like `java`, `grails` etc.

Result for above script is

```
$ lein oneoff --exec devops.clj 
....................................
Project starting...
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

[This is exactly similar problem to mine](https://github.com/Raynes/conch/issues/18#issue-42661900)

Answer (score 1):

Shell processes have two defined output streams, stdout and stderr. You are only capturing stdout. The `java -version` command does not print to stdout, it only prints to stderr.

```
user> (print (shell/stream-to-string (shell/proc "java" "-version") :out))
nil
user> (print (shell/stream-to-string (shell/proc "java" "-version") :err))
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
nil
```